# Using two urls for the same view in django?

Tags: django

So basically, how can I have two urls(or paths) for the same view in django?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if you have a view `some_view` you can define two (or more) paths, for example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/', some_view, name='foo'),
    path('bar/', some_view, name='bar'),
]
```

It is even possible to define these in two separate `urls.py`. Both will trigger the same view. It is however not very "popular" to have multiple URL patterns for the same view since usually a path explains what it does, for example `post/123/delete` likely is a view to delete a `Post` object with `123` as primary key.